# Pressing back and forward buttons when reviewing leads to weird behavior

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

When reviewing I sometimes click the **edit** link instead of the **add comment** link by mistake. Clicking the back button in the browser, I expect to get back to the question being reviewed. Instead I am directed back to the previous question I reviewed. Then clicking the forward button, gets me back to the question I originally was about to review, but it has been duplicated (see picture).

Then I add the comment I was going add in the first place and click **I'm Done**, but absolutely nothing happens. The comment seems to have been added though.

[image]

PS. Since I'm a low-rep user I'm not doing many reviews, and I don't know the behavior for example when there is no previous review to be directed to, or what happens when I click **Skip**. Any experienced reviewer out there can feel free to add more details about this bug if you have any.

Setup: Windows 7, Google Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m

Comment: I always get lost when I go into the review queue. I click on the *link* button is I want to comment etc.

Comment: I got this a while back on Stack Overflow too, the popular answer there would probably be that this is a caching issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that the inline editing form did not clean up after itself when the browser history navigation happened.

It'll be fixed as soon as the `2013.11.6.1133` release rolls out.

Comment: Is it going to be fixed on just math.stackexchange, or all the stackexchange sites?

Comment: all of them of course...

Comment: Just checking. :)